# Generating a SHA-256 hash from the Linux command line

Tags: linux, sha256

I know the string "03a34b99f22c790c4e36b2b3c2c35a36db06226e41c692fc82b8b56ac1c540c5bd" generates the SHA-256 hash `4c0b2d2f119a09b607cb273a745b2b0430d5192e0c4e536f932be5d1a6be5883` using https://privatekeys.pw/calc

However the command line

```
┌──(root㉿localhost)-[/home/kali]
└─# echo "03a34b99f22c790c4e36b2b3c2c35a36db06226e41c692fc82b8b56ac1c540c5bd" | sha256sum
92dbdf5d8231512f44fff4544d41b334ff8042db23e4dee454d4b0b61121f3ff  -

┌──(root㉿localhost)-[/home/kali]
└─# echo -n  "03a34b99f22c790c4e36b2b3c2c35a36db06226e41c692fc82b8b56ac1c540c5bd" | sha256sum
0f5b284caf3ab192b20f849b7b53d5877b83cae8b7bc617dc34104e6688ed45e  -

┌──(root㉿localhost)-[/home/kali]
└─# sha256sum <<< 03a34b99f22c790c4e36b2b3c2c35a36db06226e41c692fc82b8b56ac1c540c5bd
92dbdf5d8231512f44fff4544d41b334ff8042db23e4dee454d4b0b61121f3ff  -

┌──(root㉿localhost)-[/home/kali]
└─# sha256sum hash
92dbdf5d8231512f44fff4544d41b334ff8042db23e4dee454d4b0b61121f3ff  hash
```

Generates a different hash. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

> I know the string "03a3... " generates the SHA-256 hash 4c0b... using https://privatekeys.pw/calc

The **string** does not result in this hash. What you likely mean is not to treat the string as it is, but as hex-encoded binary data. This means you need to convert the hex string to binary first before doing the hash, like this:

```
echo 03a3... | xxd -r -p - | sha256sum
```

Comment: What about RIPEMD-160 command line hashing, when I hash the string "4c0b2d2f119a09b607cb273a745b2b0430d5192e0c4e536f932be5d1a6be588" in https://privatekeys.pw/calc it gives the output hash "9a1c78a507689f6f54b847ad1cef1e614ee23f1e" how can I do this in command line

Comment: @AvirilSmith: Your original question is answered. Please don't ask new questions in the comment. But in short: [openssl dgst](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man1/openssl-dgst.html) will provide what you need.

Comment: Yh I won't next time, but it's giving different output when I use the openssl command that's why

Comment: @AvirilSmith: it works if you a) also convert it to binary first using xxd b) don't have a typo in the string (missing final 3): `echo 4c0b2d2f119a09b607cb273a745b2b0430d5192e0c4e536f932be5d1a6be5883 | xxd -r -p - | openssl dgst -ripemd160`